# change View to ViewGroup and set Gravity for child

Tags: android

I use the custom view ArcProgress.

```
public class ArcProgress extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    protected Paint textPaint;

    private RectF rectF = new RectF();

    private float strokeWidth;
    private float suffixTextSize;
    private float bottomTextSize;
    private String bottomText;
    private float textSize;
    private int textColor;
    private int progress = 0;
    private int max;
    private int finishedStrokeColor;
    private int unfinishedStrokeColor;
    private float arcAngle;
    private String suffixText = "%";
    private float suffixTextPadding;

    private float arcBottomHeight;

    private final int default_finished_color = Color.WHITE;
    private final int default_unfinished_color = Color.rgb(72, 106, 176);
    private final int default_text_color = Color.rgb(66, 145, 241);
    private final float default_suffix_text_size;
    private final float default_suffix_padding;
    private final float default_bottom_text_size;
    private final float default_stroke_width;
    private final String default_suffix_text;
    private final int default_max = 100;
    private final float default_arc_angle = 360 * 0.8f;
    private float default_text_size;
    private final int min_size;

    private static final String INSTANCE_STATE = "saved_instance";
    private static final String INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH = "stroke_width";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_SIZE = "suffix_text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_PADDING = "suffix_text_padding";
    private static final String INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE = "bottom_text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT = "bottom_text";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE = "text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR = "text_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_PROGRESS = "progress";
    private static final String INSTANCE_MAX = "max";
    private static final String INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "finished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "unfinished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_ARC_ANGLE = "arc_angle";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX = "suffix";
    public Context mContex;
    public ArcProgress(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        mContex=context;
    }

    public ArcProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        mContex=context;
    }

    public ArcProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContex=context;
        default_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 18);
        min_size = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 100);
        default_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 40);
        default_suffix_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 15);
        default_suffix_padding = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 4);
        default_suffix_text = "%";
        default_bottom_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 10);
        default_stroke_width = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 4);

        TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcProgress, defStyleAttr, 0);
        initByAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.recycle();

        initPainters();
    }

    protected void initByAttributes(TypedArray attributes) {
        finishedStrokeColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_finished_color, default_finished_color);
        unfinishedStrokeColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_unfinished_color, default_unfinished_color);
        textColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_text_color, default_text_color);
        textSize = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_text_size, default_text_size);
        arcAngle = attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_angle, default_arc_angle);
        setMax(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_max, default_max));
        setProgress(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_progress, 0));
        strokeWidth = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_stroke_width, default_stroke_width);
        suffixTextSize = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text_size, default_suffix_text_size);
        suffixText = TextUtils.isEmpty(attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text)) ? default_suffix_text : attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text);
        suffixTextPadding = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text_padding, default_suffix_padding);
        bottomTextSize = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_bottom_text_size, default_bottom_text_size);
        bottomText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_bottom_text);
    }

    protected void initPainters() {
        textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(textColor);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
//      LayoutInflater inflater =   (LayoutInflater)mContex.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//      this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null));  

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(default_unfinished_color);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        initPainters();
        super.invalidate();
    }

    public float getStrokeWidth() {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getSuffixTextSize() {
        return suffixTextSize;
    }

    public void setSuffixTextSize(float suffixTextSize) {
        this.suffixTextSize = suffixTextSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getBottomText() {
        return bottomText;
    }

    public void setBottomText(String bottomText) {
        this.bottomText = bottomText;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        if (this.progress > getMax()) {
            this.progress %= getMax();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        if (max > 0) {
            this.max = max;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public float getBottomTextSize() {
        return bottomTextSize;
    }

    public void setBottomTextSize(float bottomTextSize) {
        this.bottomTextSize = bottomTextSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }

    public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getFinishedStrokeColor() {
        return finishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setFinishedStrokeColor(int finishedStrokeColor) {
        this.finishedStrokeColor = finishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnfinishedStrokeColor() {
        return unfinishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setUnfinishedStrokeColor(int unfinishedStrokeColor) {
        this.unfinishedStrokeColor = unfinishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getArcAngle() {
        return arcAngle;
    }

    public void setArcAngle(float arcAngle) {
        this.arcAngle = arcAngle;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getSuffixText() {
        return suffixText;
    }

    public void setSuffixText(String suffixText) {
        this.suffixText = suffixText;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getSuffixTextPadding() {
        return suffixTextPadding;
    }

    public void setSuffixTextPadding(float suffixTextPadding) {
        this.suffixTextPadding = suffixTextPadding;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight() {
        return min_size;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumWidth() {
        return min_size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        rectF.set(strokeWidth / 2f, strokeWidth / 2f, width - strokeWidth / 2f, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - strokeWidth / 2f);
        float radius = width / 2f;
        float angle = (360 - arcAngle) / 2f;
        arcBottomHeight = radius * (float) (1 - Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float startAngle = 270 - arcAngle / 2f;
        float finishedSweepAngle = progress / (float) getMax() * arcAngle;
        float finishedStartAngle = startAngle;
        paint.setColor(unfinishedStrokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, arcAngle, false, paint);
        paint.setColor(finishedStrokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, finishedStartAngle, finishedSweepAngle, false, paint);

        String text = String.valueOf(getProgress());
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            textPaint.setColor(textColor);
            textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            float textHeight = textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent();
            float textBaseline = (getHeight() - textHeight) / 2.0f;
            canvas.drawText(text, (getWidth() - textPaint.measureText(text)) / 2.0f, textBaseline, textPaint);
            textPaint.setTextSize(suffixTextSize);
            float suffixHeight = textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent();
            canvas.drawText(suffixText, getWidth() / 2.0f  + textPaint.measureText(text) + suffixTextPadding, textBaseline + textHeight - suffixHeight, textPaint);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getBottomText())) {
            textPaint.setTextSize(bottomTextSize);
            float bottomTextBaseline = getHeight() - arcBottomHeight - (textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2;
            canvas.drawText(getBottomText(), (getWidth() - textPaint.measureText(getBottomText())) / 2.0f, bottomTextBaseline, textPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH, getStrokeWidth());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_SIZE, getSuffixTextSize());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_PADDING, getSuffixTextPadding());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE, getBottomTextSize());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT, getBottomText());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE, getTextSize());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR, getTextColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_PROGRESS, getProgress());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_MAX, getMax());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getFinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getUnfinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_ARC_ANGLE, getArcAngle());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_SUFFIX, getSuffixText());
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if(state instanceof Bundle) {
            final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            strokeWidth = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH);
            suffixTextSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_SIZE);
            suffixTextPadding = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_SUFFIX_TEXT_PADDING);
            bottomTextSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE);
            bottomText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_BOTTOM_TEXT);
            textSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE);
            textColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR);
            setMax(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_MAX));
            setProgress(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_PROGRESS));
            finishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            unfinishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            suffixText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_SUFFIX);
            initPainters();
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE));
            return;
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    @Override
    protected void measureChild(View child, int parentWidthMeasureSpec, int parentHeightMeasureSpec) {

        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
            getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a view on above class. When I read some questions I found that, we should change view into the view group.

So adding below code to the class:

```
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
 }
```

The view properly added but its placed in the corner instead of the center. I want to put children in the center ArcProgress

.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

  <com.example.tesst.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#00f"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
  </com.example.tesst.ArcProgress>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to The image is placed in the center of the layer.
Sorry My language is not good

Comment: You should provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I doubt, that all code you have posted, is required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar to make easier to understand the question

Comment: sorry I want to The image is placed in the center of the layer(ArcProgress)